# Matching specific urls with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to check a string to make sure that it starts with http:// and is on the website example.com. I have this:

```
"^http://\\Bw{3}?\\.example\\.com/*"
```

Why doesn't it match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> `^https?://(?:www\.)?example\.com/?.*`

Make sure you escape the backslashes when you use this as a string in Java:

```
"^https?://(?:www\\.)?example\\.com/?.*
```

Comment: this matches "http://www. example. com" but not "http:// exampe. com" (without spaces)

Comment: @Jack S. - Nice catch! I have fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for that is exactly what the address is...

"http://www.example.com" will match that and only that.

If you're looking to match other example.com strings such as

"http://test.example.com" the RegEx is something like this

http://\w+.example.com

Maybe I don't understand the question but that's the answer to what you've asked.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see it was in Java. As Andrew Hare mentioned, you'll have to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your \B is causing the problem. You're searching for a character between two characters, followed by three w's

IN fact it is impossible for anything to match this regex: `/\Bw` because you are searching for an empty string that is either between two non-word character, or between two word characters, but you've specified that it's between a non-word character on the left (`/`) and a word character on the right (`w`).

You also searching for 0 or more forward slashes at the end, instead of a forward slash followed by 0 or more wild card characters.

Try: `^http://(?:www\\.)?example\\.com(?:/.*)?`

Comment: same as the above comment, this matches "http://www. example. com" but not "http:// exampe. com" (without spaces)

Answer (score 0):

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com(?:\/.*)?$
```